# Howto configure which POJO fields to serialize to JSON with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a List of Objects with multiple fields.   Based on the API call, the List would be returned with only a specific set of fields.  When I use transient - it does not serialize that particular field.   But, that field should be returned for another API call.  I am using Gson.

In the example below, based on the API, I wanted to print a list of Table instances with only E.g. "name" of the Table instances, or both "name" and "location", or just location.   There could be 30 fields in the Table Object.

One way is to map it to a POJO for each scenario and then print it out.  Is there a better way to do this? where you can select/choose/constrain which field gets serialized.

E.g.

```
package Testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class TestJson {

    public static Gson obGson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Table> myTable = new ArrayList<Table>();

        myTable.add(new Table("John", "Chicago"));
        myTable.add(new Table("David", "Seattle"));
        myTable.add(new Table("June", "Dallas"));

        System.out.println(obGson.toJson(myTable));

    }

}

class Table {

    String name;
    String location;

    public Table (String _name, String _location) {

        name        = _name;
        location    = _location;

    }
}
```

The output for the above looks like this.  When API-1 is called then the output should like below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "location": "Chicago"
  },
  {
    "name": "David",
    "location": "Seattle"
  },
  {
    "name": "June",
    "location": "Dallas"
  }
]
```

But when API-2 is called then the output should like below.  Only return the fields that are approved for that API call.

```
[
  {
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "name": "David"
  },
  {
    "name": "June"
  }
]
```

Similarly, the return could be managed based on the API call.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Gson will need the field declared if you want it serialize, but you don't necessarily need a Table POJO. You can serialize directly to a Map, then get any field you want

Comment: `But, that field should be returned for another API call.` What does that mean exactly?  Can you give an example of the output(s) you want to see?

Comment: @markspace, thanks for your quick reply.  I have provided an example.   I was looking for a way to manage which fields are returned.   Hope it helps to explain the situation.

Comment: @cricket_007, updated the question with an example. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `ExclusionStrategy` like

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FieldExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy { 

   @NonNull
   private final Collection<String> serializedFields;

   @Override
   public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
      if(serializedFields.contains(f.getName())) return false;
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) { return false; }

}
```

Use like

```
@Test
public void testShouldSkipField() {

   Gson gson;      
   Table table = new Table();

   Collection<String> serializedFields = new ArrayList<>();

   ArrayList<Table> myTable = new ArrayList<Table>();
   myTable.add(new Table("John", "Chicago"));
   myTable.add(new Table("David", "Seattle"));
   myTable.add(new Table("June", "Dallas"));

   serializedFields.add("name");
   gson = new GsonBuilder()
         .setPrettyPrinting()
         .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(
                new FieldExclusionStrategy(serializedFields))
         .create();
   log.info("\n{}", gson.toJson(myTable));      

   serializedFields.add("location");      
   gson = new GsonBuilder()
         .setPrettyPrinting()
         .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(
                new FieldExclusionStrategy(serializedFields))
         .create();
   log.error("\n{}", gson.toJson(myTable));      

   serializedFields.remove("name");      
   gson = new GsonBuilder()
         .setPrettyPrinting()
         .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(
                new FieldExclusionStrategy(serializedFields))
         .create();
   log.error("\n{}", gson.toJson(myTable));      

}
```

Above would log something like

> 2017-12-23 19:47:17.028 INFO  org.example.gson.FieldExclusionStrategyTest:37  -
>   [
>      {
>         "name": "John"
>      },
>      {
>         "name": "David"
>      },
>      {
>         "name": "June"
>      }
>   ]
>   2017-12-23 19:47:17.034 ERROR org.example.gson.FieldExclusionStrategyTest:44  -
>   [
>      {
>         "name": "John",
>         "location": "Chicago"
>      },
>      {
>         "name": "David",
>         "location": "Seattle"
>      },
>      {
>         "name": "June",
>         "location": "Dallas"
>      }
>   ]
>   2017-12-23 19:47:17.035 ERROR org.example.gson.FieldExclusionStrategyTest:51  -
>   [
>      {
>         "location": "Chicago"
>      },
>      {
>         "location": "Seattle"
>      },
>      {
>         "location": "Dallas"
>      }
>   ]

You need to build `GSON` again after changing list of serialized field names.

`GSON` caches internally the result - true|false - upon first call for some field name and does not query it again for cached field name.

And to add `ExclusionStrategy` you need to build `GSON` with `GsonBuilder` which then registers `ExclusionStrategy` (or many of them).

See also [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47795754/6413377) about this topic.

Comment: When you say "You need to build `GSON` again", to you mean the variable `gson`?  Are you simply emphasizing that the calls to `new GsonBuilder()` are required to change which fields get serialized?